# Python Pandas select rows based on membership of another collection (set)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, set, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` constructed as follows:

```
import pandas
import numpy

column_names = ["name", "age", "score"]
names = numpy.random.choice(["Jorge", "Xavier", "Joaquin", "Juan", "Jose"], 50)
ages = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 50)
scores = numpy.random.rand(50)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(column_names, [names, ages, scores])))
```

The top 10 rows of the above `DataFrame` looks like the following.

```
   age     name     score
0   15    Jorge  0.031380
1   44     Juan  0.373199
2   84   Xavier  0.999065
3   55     Juan  0.159873
4   55  Joaquin  0.211931
5   33     Juan  0.484350
6   22   Xavier  0.510276
7   86  Joaquin  0.490013
8    2     Jose  0.185086
9   51     Juan  0.979015
```

I want to be able to select rows for which the elements of the `name` column is a member of `{"Xavier", "Joaquin"}`. Instinctively I'm thinking of something like `df.iloc[df["name"] in {"Xavier", "Joaquin"}, :]` but that doesn't work. So how do I achieve it?

#### Note

I know I can achieve this particular example by

```
df.loc[numpy.logical_or(df["name"] == "Xavier", df["name"] == "Joaquin"), :]
```

but that's not the point. This is just a simplified example of my real problem. I have a `DataFrame` of height 2,340,923 and a name set `names` of size 3,624 and I want to select the rows whose names are members of the name set `names`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df.loc[df["name"].isin(["Xavier", "Joaquin"]), :])
    age     name     score
1    66  Joaquin  0.767056
2    17  Joaquin  0.721369
7    53  Joaquin  0.209415
10    9   Xavier  0.394815
13   20  Joaquin  0.276596
14   17   Xavier  0.810725
15   76   Xavier  0.918273
17   91  Joaquin  0.974723
18   39   Xavier  0.869607
21    3   Xavier  0.200578
22   34  Joaquin  0.938018
23   90   Xavier  0.664387
26   51   Xavier  0.946753
28   49   Xavier  0.859911
30   22  Joaquin  0.602381
34    7   Xavier  0.759837
35   96  Joaquin  0.790691
39   13  Joaquin  0.599557
40   10   Xavier  0.563933
41   69   Xavier  0.983787
43   58   Xavier  0.542903
44    8  Joaquin  0.307106
45   77  Joaquin  0.330278
46   55  Joaquin  0.980077
47   12   Xavier  0.177509
49   15  Joaquin  0.590958
```

It works with `set` nice also:

```
names = set(["Xavier", "Joaquin"])
print (df.loc[df["name"].isin(names), :])

    age     name     score
1    66  Joaquin  0.767056
2    17  Joaquin  0.721369
7    53  Joaquin  0.209415
10    9   Xavier  0.394815
13   20  Joaquin  0.276596
14   17   Xavier  0.810725
15   76   Xavier  0.918273
17   91  Joaquin  0.974723
18   39   Xavier  0.869607
21    3   Xavier  0.200578
22   34  Joaquin  0.938018
23   90   Xavier  0.664387
26   51   Xavier  0.946753
28   49   Xavier  0.859911
30   22  Joaquin  0.602381
34    7   Xavier  0.759837
35   96  Joaquin  0.790691
39   13  Joaquin  0.599557
40   10   Xavier  0.563933
41   69   Xavier  0.983787
43   58   Xavier  0.542903
44    8  Joaquin  0.307106
45   77  Joaquin  0.330278
46   55  Joaquin  0.980077
47   12   Xavier  0.177509
49   15  Joaquin  0.590958
```

Comment: Ah yes of course! I vaguely remember `isin()` at the very deep recesses of my useless brain, but I thought it was a Numpy concept and tried to search `numpy.isin()` to no avail and consequently confused myself majorly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad can help you!